# Can I change the default click-to-move behavior?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, holding the shift key prevents movement, and causes you to use your abilities in place instead of moving to where the mouse cursor is.

Is there any way to make this the default behavior? That is to say, so that clicking will not move you *unless* you depress a button?

Comment: Suggestions for a better title welcome

Comment: I have the same issue playing a Wizard. There doesn't seem to be really good solution but binding the Space key to "don't move" along with shift makes it a bit easier to control without having to do insane hand contortions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to change this behaviour.  Similar to the isometric view this is part of the gameplay Blizzard decided to retain as it encapsulates what they regard as the "feel" of the Diablo series.

The closest you can get is binding a key to "Move" which will move you towards the mouse cursor when pressed, as per [How can I avoid clicking quite so much?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66125/how-can-i-avoid-clicking-quite-so-much).