# Is there an easy way to distinguish party summons from enemies?

Tags: diablo-iii

As it stands, I'm already [clicking my damn arm off](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66125/how-can-i-avoid-clicking-quite-so-much), and more recently I've played with several Witch Doctors who summon minions that ***look like enemies***.  In a large melee, I often end up attempting to target them before, during, and after the main battle - until I find myself clicking away at a friendly while everything else is dead.  Is there some visual clue that can help me focus my Barbarian's man-wrath on the (enemy) hellspawn only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, pressing 'V' on your keyboard enables enemy health bars.

I find that easier to identify enemies and you can usually tell if you're overwhelmed as well.

Comment: It seems to me that the health bars only show on each enemy once they've been hit.  Is there any way to change that?

Comment: I keep turning that off by accident.... gaw.  That would have really helped earlier tonight.

Comment: Shows only when they've been hit? Mine shows up even before hitting them sometimes...

Comment: You could always change it in the settings, and unbind the hotkey for enemy health bars, EBongo. That way you won't keep pressing the key by mistake and making everyone look the same. You could also turn on enemy and friendly damage counters via the options menu, i find that also works towards helping you see who's who and whats attacking you for how much dmg.

Comment: Yes, I need to do that.  I just get in game and then immediately start multitasking and forget.  I was using the default banner until just the other day.  So much to tweak.