# Remapping primary skill

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm building a WW tornado barb, and my ideal skill build would be:

1. Overpower
2. Whirlwind
3. Sprint
4. Battle Rage
5. War Cry
6. Wrath of the Berzerker

However, because this build doesn't use a primary skill, I am running into issues as even with elective mode you are limited to a few select skills for your primary slot.

I can put WW in the primary, which would make the build work, but then I run into the issue of accidentally WWing while moving. **Is there any way to configure this build to avoid this problem altogether?** Like remapping Primary to another key but **not affecting the Move bound to left click.**

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to bind a move key, as outlined in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66125/how-can-i-avoid-clicking-quite-so-much).

> You can bind all movement and actions to keyboard keys. You can bind "Move" to a key, and it will move directly to where your mouse is pointed without requiring clicks.

This way, you can set a key to move to your cursor, while being able to mash whirlwhind while in combat.

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing this because my muscle memory is so firmly ingrained with click = move. Is there no way to do the opposite and bind primary without touching left click = move?

Comment: @Hidoisan Not that I know of offhand.  I'll dig around the menus when I get home, but I don't know what I'll find.  Theoretically, you use a key remapper to swap the "move" key with mouse1, but that seems like a horrible solution :/